# Auto install of web app in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, web

I've seen a similar question from nearly 2 years ago and I'm wondering if anything has changed.

I need to make the installation of a very simple web app more automatic, so that people can just click a link to install it, with maybe a confirmation button to let the iOS security know it's legitimate. The current process of having to add the shortcut to the homescreen, cuts out a large demographic that are used to more user friendly options.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid the "Add to homescreen" process is a necessary evil here (mainly due to security concerns with how the browser might interact with the springboard otherwise).

If you really don't think your audience can handle this (I'd guess that they can, if they've used a mobile browser at all), you could also add a button or popup that launches a short How-to to walk them through the process.